# ActiveMQ has correct dialect but the SQL statements are incorrect AUTO_INCREMENT instead of IDENTITY tables creation

Tags: jboss, mssql-jdbc, activemq-artemis, wildfly-15

I'm using the following:

- JBoss Wildfly 15.0.1.Final
- MSSQL JDBC connector (i.e. mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar)
- standalone-full.xml

I believe I have setup everything correctly.  The MSSQL JDBC jar is in the `modules` directory with its associated `module.xml`.  The datasource is correctly defined and functional. ActiveMQ Artemis has been setup (works fine using the file system). However when I attempt to have it use JDBC it fails trying to create the necessary tables with the following error:

```
SQLState: S0001 ErrorCode: 102 Message: Incorrect syntax near AUTO_INCREMENT'.
```

So I'm wondering what is wrong.  ActiveMQ says it supports SQL Server, and it automatically figures out which SQL dialect to use based on the return value of the driver (I've checked that name with an 6.0 version of the driver and it is the same), also in the debug output it says

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl] ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Detect database dialect as 'MSSQL'".
```

So that looks good.  So I'm a bit confused on what is wrong and would like to get it to work.  I'm providing the critical elements that I have in the `standalone-full.xml`.  Is there any other setup I need or is this a bug?

Is this also a symptom of a problem?  (i.e. see the log output...the broker is not initialized with correct driver/url that was specified by the datasource definition)

```
AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,jdbcDriverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver,jdbcConnectionUrl=null,messageTableName=AMQ_MESSAGES,bindingsTableName=AMQ_BINDINGS,largeMessageTableName=AMQ_LARGE_MESSAGES,pageStoreTableName=AMQ_PSTORE,)
```

excerpts from the standalone-full.xml settings

```
<extensions> 
   <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>
</extensions>

<datasources> 

<datasource jndi-name="java:/RMBM-DEFAULT-DS" pool-name="RMBM-DEFAULT-DS" enabled="true">
 <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://${rmbm.default.ds.host}:${rmbm.default.ds.port:1433};DatabaseName=${rmbm.default.ds.dbname}
 </connection-url>
<driver>SQLSVR</driver>
</datasource>

<drivers>
   <driver name="SQLSVR" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
      <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver- class>
   </driver>
</drivers>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:5.0">
  <server name="default">
    <journal datasource="RMBM-DEFAULT-DS" messages-table="AMQ_MESSAGES" bindings-table="AMQ_BINDINGS" 
      jms-bindings-table="AMQ_JMS_BINDINGS" large-messages-table="AMQ_LARGE_MESSAGES" page-store-table="AMQ_PGSTORE"/> 
</server>
</subsystem>
```

Here is a portion of the log output:

```
18:36:27,116 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
18:36:27,665 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:443
18:36:27,808 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.4.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
18:36:27,964 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl] (MSC service thread 1-8) Detect database dialect as 'MSSQL'.
18:36:27,968 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-8) use JDBC store for Artemis server, bindingsTable:AMQ_BINDINGS
18:36:28,065 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Starting server ActiveMQServerImpl::
18:36:28,069 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Detected no Shared Store HA options on JDBC store
18:36:28,121 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,jdbcDriverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver,jdbcConnectionUrl=null,messageTableName=AMQ_MESSAGES,bindingsTableName=AMQ_BINDINGS,largeMessageTableName=AMQ_LARGE_MESSAGES,pageStoreTableName=AMQ_PSTORE,)
18:36:28,306 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.journal.JDBCJournalImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Detect database dialect as 'MSSQL'.
18:36:28,398 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) 
SQL STATEMENTS: 
CREATE TABLE AMQ_LARGE_MESSAGES (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, FILENAME VARCHAR(255), EXTENSION VARCHAR(10), DATA BLOB, PRIMARY KEY(ID))
SQL EXCEPTIONS: 
SQLState: S0001 ErrorCode: 102 Message: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
18:36:28,425 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NULL, message=Unable to start database driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:868)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:711)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:430)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver.createTableIfNotExists(AbstractJDBCDriver.java:258)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver.createTable(AbstractJDBCDriver.java:118)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.createSchema(JDBCSequentialFileFactoryDriver.java:69)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.drivers.AbstractJDBCDriver.start(AbstractJDBCDriver.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jdbc.store.file.JDBCSequentialFileFactory.start(JDBCSequentialFileFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JDBCJournalStorageManager.init(JDBCJournalStorageManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.<init>(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:229)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JournalStorageManager.<init>(JournalStorageManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.JDBCJournalStorageManager.<init>(JDBCJournalStorageManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createStorageManager(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2155)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart1(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2296)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:64)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:535)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.6.3.jbossorg-00014//org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:376)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq//org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService.doStart(JMSService.java:206)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq//org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService.access$000(JMSService.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq//org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.jms.JMSService$1.run(JMSService.java:100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that even though the dialect is correctly detected as `MSSQL` the broker doesn't have the corresponding SQL statements to properly support it. The SQL statements for MSSQL were added in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.4 via [ARTEMIS-2202](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2202). You're using 2.6.3 so you don't have those.

Upgrading ActiveMQ Artemis in Wildfly can sometimes fail due to the tight coupling between the two so if you don't want to try upgrading you could theoretically crack open the artemis-jdbc-store jar file and add/replace these lines to `journal-sql.properties`

```
# MSSQL SQL statements
create-file-table.mssql=CREATE TABLE %s (ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY, FILENAME VARCHAR(255), EXTENSION VARCHAR(10), DATA VARBINARY(max), PRIMARY KEY(ID))
create-journal-table.mssql=CREATE TABLE %s(id BIGINT,recordType SMALLINT,compactCount SMALLINT,txId BIGINT,userRecordType SMALLINT,variableSize INTEGER,record VARBINARY(max),txDataSize INTEGER,txData VARBINARY(max),txCheckNoRecords INTEGER,seq BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(seq))
max-blob-size.mssql=2147483647
```

Regarding the `AMQ221000` log message that indicates there is an incorrect JDBC driver configuration...This is due to the fact that the ActiveMQ Artemis broker has its own JDBC driver configuration for when it's running standalone. When it's embedded in Wildfly and configured to use a `datasource` via JNDI then the standalone JDBC driver configuration isn't used. It will simply look up the specified datasource and use that.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I opted to edit the journal-sql.properties file inside the artemis-jdbc-store.jar and not upgrade the ActiveMQ.  That worked great..  Just curious, any thoughts as to why the broker is being initialized with a different driver?

Comment: Just an additional note, for my case the MSSQL specific statements did already exist in the artemis-jdbc-store.jar.  I just had to replace them, with the ones from Justin.

Comment: I updated my comment to address your question. Thanks for the update.